# PhoneGap build - Config.XML - REST CALL fails due to 'ConnectionError'

Tags: angularjs, cordova, google-play, phonegap-build

I've built an application using PhoneGap build using a custom `Config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<widget xmlns   = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
id          = "com.package"
versionCode = "25"
version     = "1.0.1" >

   <name>TEST APP</name>
   <description>TEST APP</description>

   <icon src="res/img/icon.png" />
   <icon src="res/img/icon.png" platform="android" density="ldpi" />
   <icon src="res/img/icon.png" platform="android" density="mdpi" />
   <icon src="res/img/icon.png" platform="android" density="hdpi" />
   <icon src="res/img/icon.png" platform="android" density="xhdpi" />   

   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file" />
   <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />

   <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" version="1.0.0" />  
   <access origin="*" />
   <allow-intent href="*" />
   <allow-navigation href="*" />

</widget>
```

Added Content Security Policy to the index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Build does not break - application is submitted to the PlayStore 
When triggering a REST call from the application on a HTTPS link I get an error:

```
return status '0' / return status text ''
```

The application is working locally correct in a browser , so there is no problem on REST / APP level.

I have a feeling it has to do with some missing configuration?

Any help would be welcome!

Comment: Post the code of how are you doing the REST call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dann,
You did not tell phonegap build which version to build. Such as:

```
<preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.5.0" />
```

Since you did not list this "preference", you got the latest version.

Also when using whitelist with the latest version of phonegap, I am told you need to add more information to your config.xml. For this you will want to reference the master example https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-start/blob/master/www/config.xml

You will likely need to add the pluging

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
```

If you want to limit your whitelist, instead the broad reference you have now, then read the

*Whitelist Guide*
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide

For more help on the whitelist, I recommend the google group:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/phonegap

For more help on Phonegap Build, I recommend the Official forum
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi

Comment: Hi JesseMonroy650, thanks for your answer, it got me to update the config.xml to adding the version & plugin whitelist. I've added access origin / allow-intent / allow-navigation : all to '*'. Still no luck.... The connection to the https url seems to be stopped ... Any more help on this matter ? Thanks! (updated initial post & updated config.xml)

Comment: @daan.desmedt, you list: ```<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />```perhaps you want to use the newer ```<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />```. However, I am not sure this will help.